# how to integrate MenuController in SinglePage AngularJS application with home page

Tags: angularjs, navbar, angularjs-routing

In my Angular application, i have this code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <!-- load css ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- My menu bar -->
    <nav ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
        <ul>
            <span ng-repeat="action in actions">
                <li><a href="{{action.href}}">{{action.name}}</a></li>
            </span>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" ng-view>
        <!-- content -->
    </div>

    <!-- load Angular Library -->
    <!-- load services -->
    <!-- load controllers -->
</body>
</html>
```

The content is loaded from a partial html file.

But now, I would like add a login page without the menu controller. When user is not connected, the `<nav>` bar should not be showed.

How can I place my `<nav>` bar with `MenuCtrl` without duplicate the code in each partial html file ?

Comment: I strongly suggest to use ui-router instead of the build-in ngRoute. This problem would be very easy to solve.

Comment: write a directive for the menu bar and only insert it if user is logged in

Comment: i tried ui-router instead of ngRoute, because my home page is totally different of  the other pages. i have just one form in my home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize angular's Dependency Injection by using a `factory`

[check this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NM58wX?p=preview)

**js**

```
app.factory('ShareObject', function() {

  var ShareObject = function(){};

  return ShareObject;
});

app.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, ShareObject) {
  $scope.share = ShareObject;

  $scope.login = function() {
    // Go to backend and login,
    // ...
    $scope.share.user = {
      username: 'julien_dumortier',
      name: 'Julien Dumortier'
    };

  };

  $scope.logout = function() {
    // Go to backend and logout,
    // ...
    $scope.share.user = null;

  };
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, ShareObject) {
  $scope.share = ShareObject;
});
```

**html**

```
 <!-- My menu bar -->
  <nav ng-controller="MenuCtrl">

      <div ng-show="share.user" >
        Logged in as {{ share.user.username }} 
        <a ng-click="logout()">logout</a>
      </div>
      <a ng-show="!share.user" ng-click="login()">login</a>

  </nav>

    <div class="container" ng-view></div>
```

**view**

```
<h2>Home</h2>

Logged in as {{ share.user.username }}
```